# SQL Server REGEX with multiples spaces white

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I'm trying to solve this problem in SQL Server. I need to get the customer's name when in the line there is the following condition:

Start with any [letter]/[numbers][space][numbers][space]

I used `[A-Z]/[0-9]%`, but I can't consider the space and the sequence of numbers followed by the other space

Here's the line I'm working on:

```
K/31209536                          9997530556                         RICARDO JOSE DE OLIVEIRA QUEIROZ
```

When the condition is true, I need to get the name:

```
RICARDO JOSE DE OLIVEIRA QUEIROZ
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have native RegEx support, but one thing you can do in SQL Server 2016+ (and compatibility level 130+):

```
SELECT Original, ImportantPart = REVERSE([value]) 
FROM 
(
  SELECT Original = t.StringColumn,[key],[value]
    FROM dbo.YourTableName AS t 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(
      REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(t.StringColumn))), 
    '  ', '","') + '"]')
) AS j WHERE [key] = 0;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EMQGLbop).

These kind of gymnastics certainly betray that you should better normalize your data (e.g. why isn't the name stored in its own column?).

Comment: I need it to be in regex

Comment: @JonathasSouza In RegEx _where_? As I mentioned, SQL Server doesn't support RegEx natively. You can install some 3rd party CLR stuff but that isn't supported in all versions / editions / flavors or within all organizations' security policies.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, SQL Server doesn't support full Regex.

Here is a method based on *tokenization* via XML and XQuery.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (StringColumn varchar(4000));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('K/31209536            9997530556        RICARDO JOSE DE OLIVEIRA QUEIROZ');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(2) = SPACE(2);

SELECT t.*
   , c.value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(150)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(StringColumn, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a CASE expression with a little string manipulation should do the trick

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SubY-nVP)**

```
Select CustName = case when patindex('[A-Z]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]%',SomeCol)>0
                       then right(SomeCol,charindex('  ',reverse(SomeCol))-1)
                  end
 From  YourTable
```